# Typable Variable Prompt In A Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

Here is what my batch currently looks like:

```
srcds.exe +hostname "[FAST-DL]Ultra-Realistic Apocalypse Roleplay CustomRP ALPHA" +maxplayers 8 -console -authkey 8F1B5086400AC592380B5F303778D008 +gamemode darkrp +map gm_atomic
```

How would I make it so when the window opens, I can enter a custom variable for `+map`. **|** (optional) or I can continue using the variable I previously used last time the batch was run (in the case of the sample code, it would be `gm_atomic`) **|**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "map="
set /p "map=Some prompt for map "
```

You can then detect whether someone entered a map using

```
if defined map (something) else (something_else)
```

or, perhaps

```
if defined map set "map=+map %map%"
```

then

```
srcde.exe ...whatever... %map%
```

which will add *nothing* if `map` was not entered, or *+map whateverwasentered* is there was an entry made.

You could supply a default if you wish:

```
set "map=whateveryourdefaultvalueis"
set /p "map=Some prompt for map [default:%map%]"
```

So your users need only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use the default you supply... (which may, with a little code, be derived from a file - the possibilities are limited by your imagination...)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect.
I did what you said and got the following to work exactly as planned: `set "map="
set /p "map=What Map Would You Like To Load?"
if defined map set "map=+map %map%"
srcds.exe +hostname "[FAST-DL]Ultra-Realistic Apocalypse Roleplay CustomRP ALPHA" +maxplayers 8 -console -authkey 8F1B5086400AC592380B5F303778D008 +gamemode darkrp %map%`